# Could not find package * at any version for your minimum-stability (stable). Check the package spelling or your min imum-stability

Tags: find, package, composer-php

I have pushed my project to this address:
   https://github.com/mojtabagithub/jdf-library.

But when I run this:

```
composer require rayvarzshiraz/jdf .
```

which is it's command to require, I get this error:

> Could not find package rayvarzshiraz/jdf at any version for your minimum-stability (stable). Check the package spelling or your minimum-stability.

This is my composer.json  file :

```
{
"name":         "rayvarzshiraz/jdf",
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"description":  "A module for jdf persian calender library",
"keywords": [
        "jdf",
        "persian",
        "calender",
        "symfony"
    ],
"type":         "library",
"authors": [
        {
            "name":     "Mojtaba Dehdari",
            "email":    "mojtabadehdari@gmail.com",
            "homepage": "http://jdf.scr.ir/"
        }
    ],
"support": {
    "email":    "mojtabadehdari@gmail.com"
},
"require": {
},
"autoload": {
    "files": ["lib/autoload.php"]
}
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to make it work? It seems that I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You must create a release in your GitHub repository.
For it, create a tag:
**git tag -tag_name-**
Then send the tag:
**git push origin master -tag_name-**

or

Go to your github repository and click in "releases" (this link https://github.com/mojtabagithub/jdf-library/releases) and follow the instructions.

Finally, update the packlist.org package